# Android text to text translation (french to english)

Tags: android, api

I am new to android development.
I am developing an app in which voice is converted to text (French) and then translated to English.
I have completed the first part of the app (converting voice to text in french).
I am looking for suggestions or code to translate the French text to English.
Here is the source code of voice to text translation.

```
private void promptSpeechInput() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.CANADA_FRENCH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Translate API Client Library for translation.

It supports Android 1.5 (or higher) (Note that this library's support for Android is @Beta.)

For more check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/translate/v2).